# Are there any popular works attributed to Govinda Bhagvatpada?

Tags: scripture, advaita

Govind Bhagvatpada was Guru (teacher) of Adi Shankaracharya who has preached Advaita (one of the most popular philosophy/doctrine of Vedanta). According to [Advaita Guruparampara](https://www.advaita-vedanta.org/avhp/advaita-parampara.html), he was Shisya (disciple) of Gaudapada.

Now, talking about works of Advaita Acharyas, the most popular work/contribution of Gaudapadacharya (grand guru of Adi Shankaracharya) is [Karika](http://www.swamij.com/upanishad-mandukya-karika.htm) on Mandukya Upanishad. Others are bhasya on Uttara Gita, Anu Gita, Vidya Ratna Sutra etc. Adi Shankracharya is well known for writing commentaries on [Prasthanatrayi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasthanatrayi) and numerous stotras are attributed to him.

But I have not come to know about works of Govinda Bhagvatpada. Are there any works attributed to him?

Comment: Is it ratna sutras or sri vidya ratna sutras?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi don't know. Btw, have you read Saundarya Lahari?

Comment: yes but it is not by Sankara like some.other texts its falsely attributed to him. And this is the one https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/shrividya.html?lang=sa

Comment: @RakeshJoshi ok. Who is the original author of Saundarya Lahari?

Comment: its author is disputed  and mainly it is tantric oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not popular but:
In 8
th century A.D. Govinda Bhagavatpada described Gandhaka Jarana vidhi
in Rasa Hridaya Tantra. Sri Dundukanatha, the author of Rasendra Chintamani
was the first person to introduce Kupipakwa Rasayana preparations in the
Ayurvedic therapeutics during 12th century A.D.